# How to add an event to a running thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to set an alarm using sched and thread. If I run create_alarm() once, I can create one alarm. But if I run the same function again it will say that threading has already started.

Is there a way to run the function create_alarm() more than once and having multiple alarms in the thread simultaneously.

```
import sched, time, threading, datetime

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
t = threading.Thread(target=s.run)

def trigger_alarm(name):
    print("Alarm has triggered! Alarm name: ", name)
    print("The time is now: {}".format(datetime.datetime.now()))

def create_alarm():
    alarmName = input("What is your alarm name?")
    alarmTime = input("When would you like your alarm to trigger (Format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)")
    setAlarm = time.strptime(alarmTime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    setAlarm = time.mktime(setAlarm)
    globals()[alarmName] = s.enterabs(setAlarm,1,trigger_alarm,(alarmName,))
    t.start()
    print("Your alarm has been set.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call `create_alarm`, it will run `t.start()`. A thread can only be started once, so it will fail on the second call.

You could call `t.start()` after you create the thread instead of inside this function, or you could test if `t` is already running before you call `t.start()`.